# Замена PropertyGrid из Windows Forms на аналог в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

Существует ли аналог грида для WPF? Весь гугл обспрашивал - то на платные контролы, то не в тему...

Comment: Есть в [`Extended WPF Toolkit`][1] и [`WPG.`][2] Говорят, что первый более функциональный и лучше по качеству.

[1]: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid&referringTitle=Home
[2]: http://wpg.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Родного контрола от Microsoft нет. А так, попробуйте вот это посмотреть:

[A PropertyGrid for WPF](http://wpg.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Спасибо погляжу. Как я понял, только релиза нет. Предоставляется исходный код... будем разбираться.
Да, и еще, последнее изменение датировано: "Mar 9 2011 2:53 PM", что немного настораживает... либо все доделано, либо проект заброшен...

Comment: Ну по крайней мере нужное вы можете и руками докрутить %).